# How does position: absolute - left/right work with transform: translateX/translateY?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transitions

```
.dice#dice1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translateX(-55%);
}
    
.dice#dice2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 45%;
    transform: translateX(55%);
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

The above code is resulting in the following:

[image: Result image]

Although I'm using this code I'm a little bit confused as to how the absolute left and right work with translate...

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 2):

The part that I suspect is throwing you is that the `transformX` percentage is the percentage of the width of *the positioned element itself*, whereas the top/left are percentages of the parent positioning context element.

```css
.dice#dice1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translateX(-55%);
}
```

Consider this case when:

- the containing element is 100px high and 100px wide, and
- the element being positioned is 10px high and 10px wide

The element is positioned with its top at 20px, its left at 45px, because that's 20% and 45% of the parent, respectively.

The `transformX` then moves the element left 5.5px, which is 55% of 10px, the element's own width.

Answer (score 1):

When using percentage, `left`/`right`/`up`/`down` position an element relative to the container and `transform: translate()` positions an element relative to its own dimensions.

So, `left: 50%` is half way across the container and `transform: translateX(50%)` is half of the elements width.

When an element is `position: absolute`, the `body` becomes the container, unless you add `position: relative` to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it can be inferred that first you are absolutely positioning the two `div`, here **dice1** and **dice2**, such that it's **20%** from the top and **45%** from the right.

Next after positioning the two div at the same place, you are translating **55%** from the current position, one along the **positive** x direction and the other along the **negetive** x direction.